# Ellipsis/Wrap NavigationController title at beginning in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller embedded in a navigation controller. On the controller title, i display a file's directory path.

I would like this text's ellipsis (wrap) to occur at the beginning instead of at the end as is currently the case.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a custom `UILabel` to `navigationItem's` `titleView` and set the `label's` **`lineBreakMode`** as **`.byTruncatingHead,`** i.e.

```
let label = UILabel()
label.text = "I would like this text's ellipsis (wrap) to occur at the beginning instead of at the end as is currently the case."
label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingHead
self.navigationItem.titleView = label
```

[image]